# Apple subscription for customer

Tags: iphone, membership

When developing an iOS application (freelance) for a customer, how do you handle the iOS Developer Subscription?

On the one hand, I have no problem submitting the app using my own subscription.
On the other hand, the subscription is per year which means the customer would be dependent on me actually renewing my subscription every year.

Answer (score 1):

The customer should absolutely have their own iOS developer account.

You should make it clear, **from the start** that you will provide the code (and optionally provide debug builds on your dev account), and the customer is responsible for their own developer account.

Feel free to offer assistance through the app store process.  You even get to charge for it if you feel like it.

The burden is on you to make clear that you are in no way responsible for their app store account.  Contract work is temporary by nature.  A lifelong commitment on your part is unreasonable and a huge mistake.

Comment: One client of mine just gave me his PW to his dev account and said "Take care of it."  I made sure he changed the PW later...

Answer (score 1):

They need to get their own subscription. It takes around a week for a company subscription to go through Apple. You can help them set it up but it's their responsibility to maintain it going forward.